# Evaluation of Irrational Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluation of $$\int\frac{x^4}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx$$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $$I = \int\frac{x^4}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx = -\frac{1}{4}\int x\cdot \frac{-4x^3}{(1-x^{4})^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx$$

Using Integration by parts, We get

$$I =\frac{x}{2(1-x^4)^{\frac{1}{2}}}-\int\frac{1}{(1-x^4)^{\frac{1}{2}}}dx$$

Now How can I solve after that, Help required, Thanks

Comment: Are you intrested just to use this method?

Comment: In your last integral the $3/2$ should be $1/2$ (and there should be a constant $1/2$ in front of the integral), and you have an elliptic function.

Comment: mickep would you like to explain me, Thanks

Comment: It is the rule $\int (1+x)^c\,dx=(1+x)^{c+1}/(c+1)$ that is not used.

Comment: @mickep Why isn't my solution below just using the substitution rule valid?I don't see why not,there's no special limits or expressions.

Comment: @mickup Just looked it over and I'm embarrassed. My bad. That's what happens when you do math with blurry eyes.......lol

Comment: Isn't it just $I=\dfrac{x}{2(1-x^4)^{\frac{1}{2}}}+F(1-|\arcsin(x))$?

Comment: @Colbi. It seems to be $I=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}-F\left(\left.\sin
   ^{-1}(x)\right|-1\right)\right)$  where appears the elliptic integral of the first kind (we cannot avoid it).

Comment: Can't you also try and solve it by a power series expansion of f and then integrate it term by term after determining a radii of convergence?It may not be possible since the representing series may not be uniformly convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}\,dx=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx
$$
Let $u=\arcsin x$. Then $du=1/\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx$, and we get
$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2 u}}\,du=F(-1\,|\, u)+C=F(-1\,|\,\arcsin x)+C
$$
where $F$ denotes an [elliptic integral of first kind](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticF.html). Also, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) for notational variations.

Comment: To the down voter, is something wrong with this solution?

Answer (score 2):

An elliptic integral (of the first kind) is one of the form
$$
F(t\mid k^2)=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2t}}\,dt
$$
or by substituting $x=\sin t$
$$
G(x\mid k^2)=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-k^2x^2)}}\,dx
$$
In our case, the integral 
$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}\,dx
$$
is $G(x\mid-1)$.

Comment: This is wrong. After you change to $u$, the numerator should be $(1-u^2)^{1/4}$ and not $\sqrt{1-u^2}$.

Comment: it has been corrested

Comment: No, since $(1-x^2)(1-x^2)\neq 1-x^4$.

Comment: Note that you need to take $k^2=-1$